# Getting input from text field in ViewController and using in another class

Tags: ios, string, swift

In `ViewController.swift`, I have a text field whose input I would like to use and manipulate in my other class, `Conjugate.swift`. I am capturing the input at the same time the keyboard is hidden, like so:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mainTextField: UITextField!

var input: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainTextField.delegate = self
}

/* KEYBOARD HIDE */
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    input = self.mainTextField.text
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

And then in my other class:

```
class Conjugate {
var infinitive: String!    
var isEndingAr = false

func conjugate() {

    // gets verb from text field
    infinitive = MainViewController().input

    // checks verb ending and sets value to booleans
    if (infinitive.hasSuffix("ar")) {
        isEndingAr = true
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I know that `input` in `MainViewController.swift` is still nil. I just don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `infinitive = MainViewController().input`, `MainViewController()` just creates a new instance of `MainViewController`.  That new instance never calls `textFieldShouldReturn` and therefore its `input` will be `nil`.  Instead, add a reference from `Conjugate` to `MainViewController`.

```
var mainViewController: MainViewController?
```

Then in `textFieldShouldReturn` create a `Conjugate` and assign its property:

```
let conjugate = Conjugate()
conjugate.mainViewController = self
```

Then in the `conjugate()` method, instead of creating a new view controller, refer to the property:

```
func conjugate() {

  // gets verb from text field
  infinitive = self.mainViewController!.input!

  // checks verb ending and sets value to booleans
  if (infinitive.hasSuffix("ar")) {
      isEndingAr = true
      }
  }
}
```

Also, like @emresancaktar said, `input` should be optional, since it might be nil. However, `infinitive` does not have to be optional.

Comment: This solved my problem, but now I have another problem: how do I call the conjugate method in MainViewController? Conjugate().conjugate() results in an app crash.

Comment: Again, the `Conjugate()` part just creates a new object, and since that new object has nothing initialized, the code in the `conjugate()` method will crash.  Instead of creating a new object, do `conjugate.conjugate()`.  This uses the object that was already initialized.  Also, consider using more descriptive names.  The best practice is to name objects with "noun" names, and methods with "verb" names.  Since "conjugate is both a verb and a noun (and an adjective), this naming will get very confusing very fast :)